# Regex to retrieve a substring with limited digits and unlimited special characters

Tags: python, regex

There is a text with numbers, alphabetical letters and special characters.
I need to get an exact substring(s) of that text where any number of spec.chars subset can be combined with a certain number (say, 5 and more) of digits. The substring(s) could not have anything else but numbers and spec.symbols (thus, any alphabetical symbols or non-subset spec.symbols will break it).
Here is an example:

```
Special characters: '[,%> ]'
Input: 'out >>> 23451 %% 27, where: 1155 >>    4+ %9 and 5444 off'
Output: [' >>> 23451 %% 27, ', ' 1155 >>    4']
```

Regexp like `'([0-9]{5,}|[,%> ])'` obviously not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be misunderstanding you, but perhaps something like this..

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'out >>> 23451 %% 27, where: 1155 >>    4+ %9 and 5444 off'
>>> re.findall(r'(?:[,%> ]*\d){5}[\d,%> ]*', s)
[' >>> 23451 %% 27, ', ' 1155 >>    4']
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but I think you could streamline it a bit. Try something more like this: `(?:[,%> ]*\d){5}[,%> \d]*`

Answer (score 1):

```
([>\d%,\s]+)(?=.*?\+)
```

You can try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/40